# How can I get rid of this text:u and number: infront of my list?

Tags: python-2.7, xlrd

```
import xlrd
datafile ="somefile"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(datafile)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)    
def get_cell_range(start_col, start_row, end_col, end_row):
    return [sheet.row_slice(row, start_colx=start_col, end_colx=end_col+1) for row in xrange(start_row, end_row+1)]

print get_cell_range(0,13,2,17)
```

Output

[[text:u'CENTRAL', number:4.0, number:0.0], [text:u'COASTAL', number:1.0, number:1.0], [text:u'PIEDMONT', number:5.0, number:8.0], [text:u'STUDENT', number:3.0, number:4.0], [text:u'WEST', number:4.0, number:4.0]]

Comment: Have you tried printing the contents?

Answer (score 1):

[Sheet.row_slice()](https://sourcecodebrowser.com/python-xlrd/0.6.1/classxlrd_1_1sheet_1_1_sheet.html#a4ce263731d1abe7959cf815bcdb961da) returns Cells. If you print them directly, [it](https://sourcecodebrowser.com/python-xlrd/0.6.1/classxlrd_1_1sheet_1_1_cell.html#a19c131cf43769ea6233aaa2cfe38723e) will contain type info. Try to get value by yourself.

`cells = get_cell_range(0,13,2,17)
values = [item.value for item in cells]`